# Month validation in javascript

Tags: visualforce, javascript, validation

if the month was less than today's month then I should show an error message through javascript in visualforce page.......I have tried but unable to...here is my code

```
/*javascript*/
<script type="text/javascript">
function validmonth()
{
if(exm < Month(today()))
{
condition=1;
alert("Invalid month");
jQuery(".exm").focus();
return false;
}
}
</script>

/* page */
<apex:selectlist value="{!Item.ExpirationMonth}" size="1" styleclass="exm" > 
<apex:selectOptions value="{!item.ExpireMonth}"/>
</apex:selectlist>

/* in constructor */
string dd=datetime.now().format('MM/dd/yyyy');
string mon=dd.substring(0,2);
string year=dd.substring(7,10);
item.ExpirationMonth=mon;
```

This function validmonth() Ill be calling in Command button.....

Comment: Is exm global? Seems like it needs to be a parameter to the `validmonth()` function to me.

Comment: ya it is a parameter of validmonth()....In a hurry didn't write it  var exm=jQuery(".exm").val();..is the condition if(exm < Month(today())) is correct

Comment: Would it not be a lot simpler to proxy this to the controller via an actionFunction and onComplete display a js alert if error?

Comment: It depends on the size of the viewstate - a round trip could be quite expensive.

Comment: So what would be the way for this...

Comment: Since it is a select list, it is perhaps easier to only return months current or in the future to be available for selection, unless you're concerned about legacy/older records.

Comment: For year we have done like that only(starting from 2012) but coming for month we can't do it because people have to select month & year in two seperate picklist.....so need to have a validation for it

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the LIVE Jquery Event to bind to the Change event on the Select List. Here is an example I mocked up.
I've used Javascript to get the month (0-11, hence increment by 1)

```
 <apex:page controller="TestValidateController">
    //INCLUDE JQuery Resources

    <script type="text/javascript">

    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getMonth() + 1;
    jQuery.noConflict();

//Use the Live event to bind to changes on the Select List
    jQuery(".exm").live('change',

    function ()
    {
    alert('changed ' +  jQuery(".exm option:selected").text());
    if(jQuery(".exm option:selected").text() < n)
    alert('Error');

    }
    );
    </script>

    <apex:form>
    <apex:selectlist value="{!ExpirationMonth}" size="1" styleclass="exm" > 
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!ExpireMonth}"/>
    </apex:selectlist>
    </apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```

Controller :

```
public with sharing class TestValidateController {
public integer expirationMonth {get;set;}
public SelectOption[] expireMonth {get; set;}

public TestValidateController(){
expireMonth  = new List<SelectOption>{};
for (integer inti : (new List<integer>{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}))
expireMonth.add(new SelectOption(inti+'', inti+''));

}
}
```

Comment: Hey @eagerinsf just wondering if this solved your problem ?